# Conversion from size_t to wchar_t requires a narrowing conversion

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, vector, visual-studio-2015

Trying to compile the following snippet of code

```
static std::vector<wchar_t> produceStrings(int n) {
   std::size_t vsize = 4 * n;
   auto v = std::vector<wchar_t>{ vsize };
   // ...
}
```

in VS2015 gives me the error:

```
error C2398: Element '1': conversion from 'size_t' to 'wchar_t'
requires a narrowing conversion
```

Replacing the definition of `v` by

```
std::vector<wchar_t> v(vsize);
```

however, works. Replacing `vsize` by, e.g., 10, works as well.

Why?

Edit: I am compiling for 32 bit.

Comment: With curly braces, fewer implicit conversions are considered

Comment: From where to where must be converted?

Comment: `vsize` (a `size_t`) must be convered to `wchar_t`

Comment: Hence i do not call `std::vector<wchar_t> (size_t count)` with the initializer syntax?

Comment: That's right, the `initializer_list<T>` constructor is used. The contents of the braces are elements that will be stored in the vector.

Comment: There is also the problem that the list initialiser version attempts to create a vector with one element that has a value `vsize` (hence the need for the narrowing conversion, which is no allowed) and the constructor version attempts to create a vector with `vsize` elements, each initialised to zero.    Decide what you intend to do - they are not interchangeable.

Comment: Perfect, thank you both!

Comment: In this situation (list-initialization of a class, with one initializer), the order of preference is: copy-constructor > `initializer_list<T>` > others .  The initializer_list constructor is considered viable here because there is an implicit conversion from the argument to `wchar_t`, even though the code is later deemed ill-formed because that particular conversion isn't allowd in list initialization.  (clear as mud, eh)

Comment: @M.M All the implicit conversions are *considered* (or the overload resolution wouldn't match the `initializer_list` constructor at all). It's just that actually using a narrowing conversion makes the program ill-formed.

Comment: @T.C. right, that comment was badly worded

Comment: @M.M Also, CWG is [revisiting](http://wg21.link/cwg2137) the "copy/move ctor > `initializer_list`" rule.

Comment: @T.C. Yeah it seems like an awkward one, there are some cases where the c-c is desired and some (well, at least one!) where the list is desired.

Answer (score 5):

`std::vector<wchar_t>{ vsize };` tries to create a vector with only the element `vsize` in it, which does a conversion from `size_t` to `wchar_t`.

`std::vector<wchar_t>(vsize);` constructs a vector with `vsize` elements reserved, which is perfectly fine.

Comment: It's not aggregate initialization, because vectors are not aggregates. It is list initialization, which generally forbids narrowing, and includes aggregate initialization.